# How to give permission to user after mounting a hard disk on Centos 7?

Tags: linux, centos, hard-drive, partitioning, nas

I have a HP Microserver gen 8 that i'm using as a NAS at my home, with Centos 7.

And i just got a new hard disk 2 TB, after i installed it in the bay, and rebooted the system.

I've used `fdisk` to make the partition, and after that i used:
`mkfs -t vfat /dev/sda1` to create fat32.

after i mounted : `mount /dev/sda1 /nas`

i can access it with root user and create folders .. etc, but when i access it (from SSH not samba) with my user (which is samba user also) i can only read, i can't create folders, files ... etc.

result of `fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x3833350a

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048  3907029167  1953513560   83  Linux
```

result of `ls -ld /nas`:

```
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 32K Nov  5 16:42 /nas
```

What can i do, so my user can have permissions on this mounted /nas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best would be to add some mount options for the `vfat` filesystem like `umask` or `uid/gid`.

The `uid` mount option gives a specific user the access on the mountpoint.

```
mount -o uid=user,gid=group /dev/vdd /mnt
```

Adding `umask=0` would give write access to anyone.

```
mount -o uid=user,gid=group,umask=0 /dev/vdd /mnt
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i made a folder `media` with root and when `chown abude media`, it gives me `chown: changing ownership of 'media/': Operation not permitted`, any ideas ?